# Return True or False & how to get just on true in a loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have this script that sends via $.post some information

```
$("#clickme").click(function(e){  
var selected = $(".img input:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.name;}).get();
var prelucrare = selected.join(";")
$.post('test.php', {
    rezultat: prelucrare,    
},

function(data){
    $('#rez').html(data)
});  
});`
```

And the PHP file that handles the $.post

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
If(isSet($_POST['rezultat'])) {
$d = explode(';', $_POST['rezultat']);

foreach($d as $numar_inregistrare){
    $SQL = "DELETE FROM galerie_foto WHERE numar_inregistrare = '$numar_inregistrare'";
    $rezultat = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    return true;          
}
} else {
exit;
}
?>
```

I have two questions: 
1. How can I make the js script do a thing if the return value is true and an other thing if the return value is false ? Something like this ?

```
  $.post('test.php', {
  rezultat: prelucrare,
       success: function(msg){
        valid = (msg == 1) ? true : false;
        if(!valid) {
            $("#valid_input").html("Please enter valid info");
        } else {
            $("#valid_input").html("");
        }
     }
   )};
```

1. My other question is about the returning result, because I'm in a loop if there are 3 things in the array the result will be truetruetrue instead of just one true, what can I make to get just one true ?

Comment: `return = true;` is not valid syntax. Did you mean `return true;` or `$return = true;`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean return true;

Comment: Since your code isn't in a function, the return value doesn't go anywhere, the script just exits. If you want to send results to the AJAX caller, you have to use `echo`.

Comment: And if you want to send an array of results, use JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "return" only in functions and methods. To print "true" or "false" once, in the foreach loop you can break out or in your case just exit with 'false' if there's an error. You'll have something like this:

```
foreach($d as $numar_inregistrare){
    $SQL = "DELETE FROM galerie_foto WHERE numar_inregistrare = '$numar_inregistrare'";
    $rezultat = mysql_query($SQL);

    if (!$rezultat) {
        exit('false');
    }
}

echo 'true';

....
```